# Upload files to the cloud with the DropBox API

Tags: javascript, php, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload chunks to DropBox cloud based on this Git doc https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/wiki/Upload-and-Download-Files
generally works fine, when I try to upload a simple file like an image upload it to the cloud without problems.

The problem is when I try to upload a video it weighs about 100MB or more.
Following documentation when trying to upload fragmented files
[image]

I integrate it into my code but I can't get it to upload the video or the file that weighs more than 100 MB.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="btnenviar" id="btnenviar" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
require_once 'terceros/dropbox/vendor/autoload.php';
use Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox;
use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp;

$dropboxKey =“mike”;
$dropboxSecret =“mysecret”;
$dropboxToken=“mytoken”;


$app = new DropboxApp($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret,$dropboxToken);
$dropbox = new Dropbox($app);

if(!empty($_FILES)){
  $nombre = uniqid();
  $tempfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $ext = explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']);
  $ext = end($ext);
  $nombredropbox = "/" .$nombre . "." .$ext;

  $fileSize = 400000000;
  $chunkSize = $fileSize / 4;

  try{
    //$file = $dropbox->simpleUpload( $tempfile,$nombredropbox, ['autorename' => true]); --> Upload Image

    $file = $dropbox->uploadChunked($tempfile,$fileSize,$chunkSize, ['autorename' => true]);  //-->Upload videos
    echo "file uploaded";
  }catch(\exception $e){
    print_r($e);

  }



}


?>
```

Comment: Have your checked your upload size / request size limit in PHP / Apache / Nginx?

Comment: What error are you getting?